# RPM %files, how to specify a different build and install path for a file rather than having them the same

Tags: rpmbuild

I'd like to specify a different build and deployment path for files, how can I specify this? I have a directory of files on my build box at pathA,and would like to install these on pathB.

```
%files subpackagetest
%defattr(0644,%{_package_owner},%{_package_owner},0755)
/source/path/on/build/box /deployment/path
```

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 3):

Look at the %install section of the spec file.  Something like below should do the trick.

```
%install 
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/deployment/path
cp -R /source/path/on/build/box %{buildroot}/deployment/path

%file subpackagetest
%defattr(0644,%{_package_owner},%{_package_owner},0755)
/deployment/path
```

See http://www.logiqwest.com/TechnicalPapers/rpmScriptInstall.html for an example.